# Passing a linked list to a function and making sure it is not modified

Tags: c++, algorithm, methods, linked-list, object-oriented-analysis

Is there a way to pass a linked list to a function and ensuring that it is not modified?

We can pass a const head pointer to a function, and this will make sure that the head is not modified. However, the function could access other nodes from head and modify those.

Comment: if data integrity have to be concerned between function calls , pass a copy of the entire list.

Comment: You can use a `std::list`, then you pass a constant object.

Comment: In the presence of `const_cast`, you can't make sure that something isn't modified. The best you can do is pass a copy of the thing you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to try something like this:

```
class Node{
  private: 
    Node* _next;  
  public:        
    Node(Node* next) : _next(next){}

    Node* getNext(){ return _next; }
    const Node* getNext() const {return _next; }
};
```

p.s. IMHO. C++ prorammers very often ignore references and use pointers in places they not needed. May that be an option for your case? :)

```
struct Node{ Node& _next; Node(Node& next) : _next(next){} };
```

PP.SS. The second getNext may be not needed in your concrete case. It is just to make the life easier if you have functions taking const node pointers. In the example below I will try to clear the idea with const-method a bit more :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Node{
  private: 
    Node* _next;  
  public:        
    Node(Node* next) : _next(next){}

    Node* getNext(){ std::cout << "getNext\n";  return _next;  }
    const Node * getNext() const { std::cout << "getNext const\n";  return _next; }
};

void f1(Node* node){ node->getNext(); }
void f2(const Node* node){ node->getNext(); }

int main() {
        Node* n1 = new Node(NULL);
        Node* n2 = new Node(n1);        
        f1(n2);
        f2(n2);
}
```

Comment: depending on the task another option would be using references instead of pointers.

struct Node{
  
    Node& _next;  
    
    Node(Node& next) : _next(next){}
};

Comment: I'm not sure I understood this entirely. Two questions: 1. Why have 2 getters (one plain and one const) for _next? Since _next is private for a Node, having a plain pointer to Node won't let you modify _next, which is as good as having a const pointer to Node. 2. How would I modify a Node's _next pointer?

Comment: The idea with the second getNext method was that whenever a function tries to get get next-pointer from a const node pointer, it must be given another CONST node pointer. Just to make easier working with functions that take. May be for your concrete task it is not needed :)

I will change the code to make the idea a bit more clear )

Answer (score 0):

if you want to traverse through the linkedList Without changing it,
just overload your traversal functions with constant ones.